# Running out of Memory with POS Tagging in R

Tags: r, twitter, nlp, data.table

I'm hoping there is a better way to do this. I have a data.table with tweets: 8018 of them. I am using data.table function to do POS tagging on each tweet.

data.table:

```
Tweet
Sample Tweet 1 :)
sample tweet 2
```

Function for POS tagging:

```
tagPOS =  function(x) {
   s <- as.String(x)
   sent_token_annotator = Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
   word_token_annotator = Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
   a2 = annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
   pos_tag_annotator = Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
   a3 = annotate(s, pos_tag_annotator, a2)
   a3w = subset(a3, type == "word")
   POStags = unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
   return(paste(POStags,collapse = " "))
}
```

Getting POS:

```
dat[,c("ID"):= .I]
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx10g" )
dat[,c("POS"):= tagPOS(Tweet),by = .(ID)]
```

Even with setting the memory I'm getting this error:

```
Error in .jnew("opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel",    .jcast(.jnew("java.io.FileInputStream",  : 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=r+"GC+overhead+limit+exceeded"

Comment: @lukeA are you just pointing out adding the option `options( java.parameters = "-Xmx10g" )`? I already have that in my code and it still isn't working...

Comment: Did you place the options statement before any library calls?

Comment: @lukeA yeah, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
options(java.parameters = "- Xmx3000m")
library(rJava)
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)
library(data.table)
tagPOS <-  function(x) {
  s <- as.String(x)
  sent_token_annotator = Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
  word_token_annotator = Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
  a2 = annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
  pos_tag_annotator = Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
  a3 = annotate(s, pos_tag_annotator, a2)
  a3w = subset(a3, type == "word")
  POStags = unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
  gc()
  return(paste(POStags,collapse = " "))
}
dat <- data.table(Tweet = rep("This is a tweet.", 10000L))
dat[,c("ID"):= .I]
dat[,c("POS"):= tagPOS(Tweet),by = .(ID)]
```

Comment: So it looks like adding gc() fixes the issue. It's incredibly slow though. I started the program about 10min ago and it's still running. Do you know if there is any more efficient want to run this?

Comment: Well, it finally finished running. It does work but it takes 1.5 hours to run. I guess this is technically solved though so I can close the question, but if you have any idea how to improve the speed that would help me a ton.

Comment: Never mind, changed the function around to pass the Maxent and it runs in 9 minutes now.

Comment: One way to increase speed would be to run it in parallel. How exactly did you change the function in order to speed things up?

Comment: @Kristofersen , what do you mean about passing the Maxent? I'm dealing with a similar issue, and I really want to speed my code up too.